# mysql query date erro

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mybatis

Why is the difference between the time of the database query and the result 13 hours？

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the timezone set in your DB configuration, I think it could be due to that, to check the timezone in mysql you can refer below documentation :

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html